# SQL server Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired on azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, entity-framework-core, timeout

I am using external SQL Server to host our database and ASP.NET MVC Core application is hosted on Azure. Locally on Dev machine, the Web application works fine when a complex query executed but on Azure I get an exception

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired
```

I am using the same database and connection string, also we do not use Azure SQL we use our own SQL Server which is hosted remotely. Why complex queries stop working on Azure, I have no idea where to look for the problem.

The connection string:

```
data source=xx.xx.xx.xx;initial catalog=ca-xx;user id=ca-xx;password=xxxx;connection timeout=600
```

Comment: it could be due to network latency hence you need to increase the command timeout

Comment: @MukeshArora the connection timeout is set to 600 seconds and I get "Execution Timeout Expired" after about 10 seconds. Also, queries run pretty fast in under 5 seconds. All other simple selects works fine, I only have problems with select and grouping.

Comment: I have suggested increasing the command timeout of SQL command Object, by default it is 30 seconds but if you are getting error in 10 seconds, then not sure what could be the reason but still, you can give a try by increasing command timeout.

Comment: Have you tried to run the query directly in DB using SQL Management Studio?

Comment: I think you have a credential issue. I would first run SQL Server Management Studio on machine where you are having issues.  Install if you do not have it locally.  It is a great way of debugging issues.  Then connect to the remote SQL Server database using SSMS.  If you get a connection error with SSMS then you have a credential issue.  Usually you should be using Windows Credentials and not a user name and password.  Try both with SSMS.  Once you connect try a simple query just to make sure you have access to the database.  Also check in SSMS explorer under database you have ca-xx.

Comment: @jdweng The connection is fine because simple queries run and database accessible.

Comment: Is the initial catalog correct?  I would still try your exact query using SSMS.  The SSMS errors are much better than in c#.  You still may have a credential issues not being able to access all the tables in the server.  SSMS will give an error indicating what table is the problem.  Failing in 5 seconds sounds more like an access issue than a timeout since the default timeout is 30 seconds.  When executing the query from SSMS add : Use ca-xx;  which is equivalent to the initial catalog.

Answer (score 0):

When utilizing the Azure Sql database and the Azure Release, I had the identical problem. I discovered that the database performance is an issue. It works well once I upgraded the database's DTUs.

[image]